# Datatable.js stateSaveCallback with Ajax Data

Tags: php, jquery, datatable, datatables

I can populate my datatable via ajax and i can also save the state in the database via ajax.

The problem is that when refreshing the page, I need to bring the data via ajax, but I also need to query the database and bring the saved data from the table configuration that is with `stateLoadCallback.`

```
  var dataTable = $('#datatable').DataTable({
        processing: true,
        searching: false,
        responsive: false,
        serverSide: true,
        searchDelay: 5000,
        stateSave: true,
        dom: 'Bfrtip',
        bSort: true,
        scrollX: true,

        ajax: {
            url: "app/get/users",
            type: "POST",
            dataType: "json",
            data: function(d) {
               var frm_data = $('#searchForm').serializeArray();
               $.each(frm_data, function(key, val) {
                    d[val.name] = val.value;
                })
            },
            dataSrc: function(data){
                if(data == "no data"){
                    return [];
                }
                else {
                    return data.aaData;
                }
            },
        },
        stateSaveCallback: function(settings,data){
            $.ajax({
                "url": "app/settings/state/users",
                "data": data,
                "dataType": "json",
                "type": "POST",
                "success": function () {}
            });
        },
            stateLoadCallback: function (settings, callback) {
                $.ajax( {
                    url: "app/settings/state/users/load",
                    dataType: 'json',
                    type: "POST",
                    success: function (json) {
                        callback( JSON.parse(json) );
                    }
                } );
            },
        columns: [
           {data: 'id', name: 'id', title: 'Id'},
           {data: 'image', name: 'image', title: 'Image'},
           {data: 'name', name: 'name', title: 'Name'},
         ],
         
        select: {style: 'multi'}
    })
```

How can I join `stateLoadCallback` with `ajax` ?

Comment: I am not sure I understand what you want to do here. When you use `stateSave: true`, you save state such as pagination position, display length, filtering and sorting. But when you use `serverSide: true`, you already send that data to the server as part of the standard server-side request data (the [sent parameters](https://datatables.net/manual/server-side#Sent-parameters)). So that contains everything you should need, already - no need for extra DataTables "state saving" logic. I suppose you would need to detect when the `draw` parameter is `1` (or maybe it's `0`) to indicate a new session.

Comment: @Andrew James from what I understand in the documentation, through `serverSide: true` the datatable.js does not send as a parameter if the column is visible or not.

That's why I'm trying to save via `stateSaveCallback`

Comment: OK - good point. That is probably worth adding to the question, as a clarification.

Comment: I took a closer look at this, and I am using your code successfully to send state (including column visibility) to the server, and returning state back from the server. So, I am wondering what specific error or problem you are facing. Would you be able to update your question? The only thing I am doing differently from the code in your question is I am using `callback( json );` in the `stateLoadCallback` success function (not `JSON.parse(json)`). And, also, I am not using a PHP web server, I am using Java/Tomcat.